# how to implement rubberband selection for list of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of items and I need to select multiple items by drag select. I was tried to implement it. my code not working properly.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zZTfA/3/)

```
var dragging=false,rbt,rbl;
$(".itemlist").bind({"mousedown":handleMouseDown,
                     "mousemove":handleMouseMove,
                     "mouseup":handleMouseUp,});



function handleMouseDown(e){
    var rubberband = $("<div/>").addClass("fmgrRubberBand").appendTo(this);
    rubberband.css({
        top : e.pageY,
        left : e.pageX
    });
    rbt = e.pageX;
    rbl = e.pageY;
    dragging=true;
}
function handleMouseMove(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (dragging) {
        var t = $(this).children(".fmgrRubberBand").offset().top;
        var l = $(this).children(".fmgrRubberBand").offset().left;
        if (l < e.pageX) {
            $(this).children(".fmgrRubberBand").css({
                "width" : e.pageX - l + "px"
            })
        } else {
            $(this).children(".fmgrRubberBand").css({
                "width" : rbl - e.pageX + "px",
                "left" : e.pageX
            });
        }
        if (t < e.pageY) {
            $(this).children(".fmgrRubberBand").css({
                "height" : e.pageY - t + "px"
            })
        } else {
            $(this).children(".fmgrRubberBand").css({
                "height" : rbt - e.pageY + "px",
                "top" : e.pageY
            })
        }

    }
        
}
function handleMouseUp(e){
    e.preventDefault();
                        
    dragging = false;

    $(this).children(".fmgrRubberBand").remove();
}
```

how can I select multiple items by using the band selection?

my needs are:

1. drag the band over list items.
2. and select the items under the band covered area

Comment: also your selection is not working when dragging upwards.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? Google it and use library someone already made. Like this one for example http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection

Comment: Cache the queries, man. Don't repeat `$(this).children(".fmgrRubberBand")` every time: save it to a variable and use it every time you need it.

Comment: @christoph yah something wrong in my calculation

Comment: new fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/zZTfA/5/

Comment: @WTK sorry I was already bind the draggable and droppable to items in my code,

Comment: @wtk using a library is no big deal, every fool with hardly no skill can do- reinventing the wheel proves it could as well have been you inventing it in the first place.

Comment: @Christoph Of course it's no big deal, it shouldn't be. Unless you really want to write some new great library to handle items selection on page or do that just to learn - be my guest. But if it's just a small piece of functionality of a project what's the point of pushing the idea of writing the same stuff yet another time? For most part, it's better to use your time and effort in (presumably) innovative parts of your project rather than trying to write every piece of code by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use jquery ui selectable plugin.

Here is working demo.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zZTfA/11/)

```
$(".itemlist").selectable({filter:"li"});
```